# Link error 2019 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 for C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 IDE, which compiles my C source code (C code emitted by MB86/Cbasic translator to C) OK but when I try to run the .exe file, it displays several errors, such as Error LNK2019  unresolved external symbol __mbprnt referenced in function _main. Could anyone help in fixing the errors? I use Windows 10 desktop computer.

Comment: Check your build configuration, and see if all the header files are included. Some functions are defined in the headers. Missing definition of functions might cause linker errors

Comment: how to ensure all lib file names are specified for successful linking to create an exe file? I am new to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 IDE.

Comment: I have found the following lib file names (in which folder do these lib files reside?) ​specified under Configuration Properties>Linker> Input> Additional dependencies
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: I added cb32.lib and placed cb.h and cb32.lib in this folder: C:\Users\srjha\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test1\Test1. Now both cb.h and cb32.lib are found by the linker. Now only 2 errors remaining: 2019: Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _sprintf referenced in function __mbftoa_ieee Test1 c:\Users\srjha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test1\Test1\cb32.lib(MB86F2.OBJ)  AND Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function _Inkey Test1 c:\Users\srjha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test1\Test1\cb32.lib(WINCONSOLE.OBJ)

Comment: Can you post screen shot of your code and the solution explorer?

Comment: Thanks. Please download from my following link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/lue4nqp479x27wg/Chen.zip

Comment: Can you send me CB.h?

Comment: thanks, please download from: http://www.mediafire.com/view/iatogievhk2zvct/CB.h If you need any other file, let me know.

Comment: Could I use MS Visual Studio Express 2010 IDE (if MS Visual Studio Community 2015 IDE cannot be used) instead of using my current programmer's Notepad in which I use xx32.cmd batch file to compile and link. For downloading xx32.cmd: http://www.mediafire.com/download/4m7449ezmd66pxd/ad32.cmd